# Event of clicking checkout button

Tags: magento-1.8, checkout, event-observer

At the moment I have an observer running on the sales_quote_save_before event to check if the customer's cart has a subtotal greater than £100 if they belong to a particular customer group.

This works well besides from it runs every time the customer adds a product to their basket. I only want to run my code if they try to go to the checkout page rather than just viewing the basket page.

Could anyone advise of the event I would need to use

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use the event `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_index`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few events you can use during checkout. My first advice based on your question would be to use: **checkout_onepage_controller_success_action**

To check a list of all checkout events see this:
https://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magento/magento-programming/633-events-with-magento-checkout

For a generic list of events for magento 1.8 check this:
https://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-8/

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve it if they(user) try to click shipping or billing address
(continue button) at this check point write an observer for your logic.